# Displacement maps in Eevee

Tags: materials, node-editor, displacement, eevee-render-engine

How do I apply Displacement map in Eevee? Unlike Cycles, the Output node in Eevee does not have any input for Displacement.

Comment: Use a displacement modifier instead, or use a bump map

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos: Thanks, but there is no input for bump map either.

Comment: You need to add a vector > bump map node to convert the texture into normal and feed it to the normal input of the eevee node.

Comment: @Cebbi you should probably post that as an answer below. Just elaborate a bit on how to do it and why, if relevant add some screenshots.